# Visualize timestamped data in JSON for analytics purposes

Tags: json, charts, google-analytics, data-visualization

I have a JSON output of my users doing things on my website (via Firebase backend) that looks something like this:

```
{
"24iKM1Zublcm2XhVV3yVHNcxilg1" : {
"1488592280222" : "logIn",
"1488592283993" : "shop_home",
"1488592285337" : "about",
"1488592288721" : "onBoardingOnSlideChanged_1",
"1488592288725" : "onBoardingSkip_1",
"1488592313524" : "shop_cat_shirts",
"1488592317712" : "shot_cat_shoes",
"1488592348853" : "shot_cat_shirts",
"1488592353155" : "shop_home",
"1488592360107" : "logOut",
"1488659428635" : "logIn",
"1488659430033" : "shop_home",
"1488659438844" : "shop_cat_shoes",
"1488682041437" : "logOut",
},
```

...and so on, for each user.

I'm trying to get some analytics here. For example, how many times did the user above visit the "shop_cat_shoes" page over a date range.

Are there any off-the-shelf tools I could use?

If not, what set of libraries and what steps do I need to take to normalize this data?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this firebase analytics or google analytics you are getting the data from?

Comment: No, its a json export of data we gather ourselves